# Using lynx in a shell, store dump for further grep

Tags: bash, lynx

is it possible in bash script to do something like get web page content as a browser using lynx
store it in a variable (actually only one network access to the page) and then do many grep to extract information ?

i have tried things like :

```
content="$(lynx -dump -nolist $url')"
var1=`cat "$content" | grep myre1`
var2=`cat "$content" | grep myre2`
```

but i mess up between assignations, using quotes, backquotes and so on.

if someone have another solution without lynx: i am searching for something like `lynx --dump` that is "browser rendering view" (and not `wget`) and preferably would avoid creating a file on system (or if this is the only solution, how may i proceed to delete this temporary file?)

thank u and best regards

Comment: Didn't know about lynx before. Thanks :)

Comment: `lynx -dump` is a great feature, also think of `lynx -useragent="Mozilla/5.0"` that may be useful... i do not know if there are other alternatives to see webpages in "human" text mode so easily.

Comment: you have a stray single quote after $url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fixed your code. 
And I want to answer to this

> but i mess up between assignations, using quotes, backquotes and so on.

- Please prefer `$()` instead of backticks, usually there is no difference, but one great advantage of `$()` is that you can nest it. Also in some fonts backticks could look similar to single quotes and if you paste your code to some sites it may break, so $() is more stable.
- Always place `" "` around parameters. Examples: `echo "$myvar"` , `wget "$myurl"`
- Use `[[ ]]` instead of `[`. `[` is a `test` command located in /bin/test (and /bin/[ is usually symlinked to /bin/test), while `[[ ]]` is bash syntax. (However it seems like [ is a bash builtin now)
- Do not use `let` for math operations, use `(( ))`. Examples: `(( a = 5 * b ))` , `echo $(( a / 20 ))`
- Use `(( ))` for math comparisons instead of `[[ ]]` since it allows intuitive `<=` `<` `>` `>=` operators. Example: `if (( a <= b )); then ...` instead of `if [[ $a -le $b ]]; then ...`
- Prefer bash string manipulations instead of `tr` and other utilities. [Some of them](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and [A bit more](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073). Example: use `${myvar^^}` instead of `echo "$myvar" | tr a-z A-Z`
- Most of the commands allow you to specify filename. For example, do not use `cat filename | grep somestr` , use `grep somestr filename` instead.

Your fixed code:

```
content=$(lynx -dump -nolist "$url")
var1=$(grep myre1 <<< "$content")
var2=$(grep myre2 <<< "$content")
```

Comment: thank u for this interesting reply :) learn many things here !

Comment: please can you post a line example with `(( ))`and `[[ ]]`? doing `echo ((4 + 5))` or `print [[4<=5]]` do not work for me

Comment: well maybe a last question when using `echo "$var1"` i can get `\n` (newline) protected, how should i proceed to replace them? is this the preferred way:  `echo "${var1//$'\n'/ }"`? ... not so obvious :)

Comment: I am not following you, are you trying to replace ``\n`` with real line breaks? There's -e flag, try ``var1='hello\nworld'; echo -e "$var1"``. Also see ``man echo`` for more info.

Comment: no i want to replace `\n` with space, actually this question is related to which one is best `echo "var1 var2"` or `echo "$var1" "$var2"` (that is separate variable with a space and before doing that remove `\n` to have anything on one single line)

Comment: ``var1='hello\nworld'; echo "${var1//'\n'/ }"`` to replace new lines with spaces. Now, ``echo "$var1 $var2"`` vs ``echo "$var1" "$var2"``... it depends on what you want to happen. When using first variant, only one parameter is passed (which contains space). When using second variant two variables are passed as different parameters. It does not matter with ``echo`` command, but it matters for other commands. For example: ``a='hello'; b='world'`` , ``rm "$a $b"`` is going to remove a file which is named ``hello world`` , but rm "$a" "$b" is going to remove two files: ``hello`` and ``world``

Comment: Please do **not** use `[[ $a == $b ]]` unless you mean for `$b` to be interpreted as a glob pattern rather than a literal string. You could use `[[ $a == "$b" ]]`, but I'd actually argue for `[[ "$a" == "$b" ]]` because there's absolutely nothing wrong with it (the quotes around `$a` don't do any good, but they don't do any harm either), and because it's safest to you think of double-quoting expansions as the default -- something you should do unless there's a positive reason not to. This way you won't have to keep track of all the odd cases (like `$b`) where they're truly needed.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Could you please point out why do you have to quote ``"$b"`` ? I've tried this ``a='*'; b='*'; [[ $a == $b ]] && echo yes || echo no`` and got ``yes``. There are some files in the current directory. So could you give an example when non-quoted $b could result in a bug?

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko: try `a='not an asterisk'; b='*'; [[ $a == $b ]] && echo yes || echo no` -- that also prints `yes`, because the `*` in `$b` will match any string.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You're right! Seems like I was wrong for a long time, I have to review my answers... Thanks

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko: BTW, it's actually even weirder (and cleverer) than you might realize, since you can quote *part of* the right side, and it'll treat the quoted parts literally and the unquoted as glob patterns. E.g. `b='*'; [[ $a == "$b"$b ]]` will match a any string that begins with a literal asterisk.