# Bash is symlinking to working directory instead of specified directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink

I am working on a bash script that I am working on for a universal Linux dotfile install script.  I am attempting to get the symlinking working but I have been bashing (no pun intended) my head against the wall trying to figure out why the symlinks will not work and the copying will not work.  I currently have this separated into multiple files so I don't have if statements three miles long.

ultimate-install.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# The ultimate install script for all dotfiles.

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Please specify the directory where all of you dotfiles are located."
    exit 1
fi

# Makes sure that the directory does NOT have a trailing slash!
if [[ ${1:(-1)} == "/" ]]; then
    DOTFILE_DIR=${1:0:${#1} - 1}
else
    DOTFILE_DIR="$1"
fi

# TODO: Clean this mess up and make it more concise.
if [[ -z "$2" ]]; then
    if [[ ! -d $HOME/.config/old_dotfiles ]]; then
        mkdir "$HOME/.config/old_dotfiles"
    fi
    BACKUP_DIR="$HOME/.config/old_dotfiles"
else
    if [[ -d "$2" ]]; then
        BACKUP_DIR="$2"
    else
        mkdir "$2"
        BACKUP_DIR="$2"
    fi
fi

read DECISION

if [ $DECISION == "N" -o $DECISION == "n" ]; then
    echo "Aborting installation!"
    exit
fi

read DECISION

echo

if [ $DECISION == "N" -o $DECISION == "n" ]; then
    source src/no-prompts.sh "$DOTFILE_DIR" "$BACKUP_DIR"
else
    source src/prompts.sh "$DOTFILE_DIR" "$BACKUP_DIR"
fi

echo "Installation complete.  Old dotfiles are backed up to $BACKUP_DIR."
```

src/no-prompts.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Maintained by Daniel Seymour

DOTFILE_DIR="$1"
BACKUP_DIR="$2"
TEST_DIR="/home/daniel/dotfile-test"

function no_prompt_install(){
    FILE_NAME="$1"
    if [ "${FILE_NAME:0:1}" == "." ]; then
        ln -s "$FILE_NAME $TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
    else
        ln -s ".$FILE_NAME $TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
    fi
}

# TODO: implement a check for file type and deal with unknown files.
for FILE in $DOTFILE_DIR/*; do
    cp $FILE $BACKUP_DIR
    no_prompt_install $FILE
done
```

src/prompts.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Maintained by Daniel Seymour

DOTFILE_DIR="$1"
BACKUP_DIR="$2"
TEST_DIR="/home/daniel/dotfile-test"

function prompt_install {
    FILE_PATH=$1
    FILE_NAME=${FILE_PATH##*/}
    echo "Would you like to install $FILE_NAME? [Y, n]"
    read DECISION
    if [ $DECISION == "n" -o $DECISION == "N" ]; then
        echo "Not installing."
        return
    else
        # TODO: Clean this up into one statement.
        if [ ${FILE_NAME:0:1} == "." ]; then
            rm -rf "$TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
            ln -sn "$FILE_PATH $TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
        else
            FILE_NAME="."$FILE_NAME
            rm -rf "$TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
            ln -sn "$FILE_PATH $TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
        fi
    fi
}

# TODO: implement a check for file type and deal with unknown files.
for FILE in $DOTFILE_DIR/*; do
    cp $FILE $BACKUP_DIR
    prompt_install $FILE
done
```

The above is trimmed for long `echo` statements that do a lot of explaining.

The basic idea of this script is to take as many as two arguments (the dotfile directory to install and if specified, the custom backup directory, $1 and $2 respectively). The script should then copy all of the files in the target directory to BACKUP_DIR and symlink all of the dotfiles in the DOTFILE_DIR to TEST_DIR. (TEST_DIR will be $HOME in the production scripts.) Great in theory, right?

The complication comes when I run the script. None of the files are copied or symlinked as they should be. Instead, I end up with NO copy (probably due to the same issue as the symlink not working) and a broken symlink in the current directory.

One last piece of information. I am executing the file from the directory that contains ultimate-install.sh (/home/daniel/Projects/Git-Repos/Ultimate-Dotfile-Install-Scripts).

So where did I go wrong?

PS Please don't comment on the TODOs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Your quoting is wrong.

```
ln -sn -- "$FILE_PATH" "$TEST_DIR/$FILE_NAME"
```

**Longer answer**

This does not really relate to your problem, but I want to point it out.

- Do not use `""` inside `[[ ]]`, so instead of this `if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then` use this `if [[ -z $1 ]]; then`
- What is the point of making sure that directory does not have a trailing slash? It has no effect! `/usr/bin/` is the same directory as `/usr/bin` or `/usr////bin` or `/usr////////bin//////`
- Do not check if a directory exists when creating directories. Use `-p` option! Example: `mkdir -p "$HOME/.config/old_dotfiles"`
- Instead of `if [ $DECISION == "N" -o $DECISION == "n" ];` use `if [[ ${DECISION^^} == N]];`
- I have another great answer about bash code style [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353909/2698019). Please check it out! Also read the comments, since I was explaining there exactly your issue.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. And thank you for the critiquing on the script style. Off topic, do you have any good guides to learning bash script style rules? As you can probably tell, I am a bit new to bash scripting.

Comment: @DaBungalow None that I know of. Most important stuff is in the link to the answer that I have provided. For everything else, just try to search alternatives and choose the best one. Usually there is more than one way to do the same thing in bash.

Comment: @DaBungalow This site has amazingly great info about bash http://mywiki.wooledge.org/